# Cannot start a service after "Install a service" action in Install4j

Tags: install4j

Until now, we installed and started out services with *"Run executable or batch file"* action and it worked fine.
I want to switch these actions with new *"Install/start/stop a service"* respectively actions, so I tried doing it with moderate steps - first switching the 1st executable install action with *"Install a service"* action.

It seems the installer do install the service but it won't start it. when I try to manually start it - I'm getting the error:

```
error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
```

I doubled checked myself & both old executable action and the new "*Install a service*" action are configured the same, while the only different between them, is that on the *executable* action I also configured the *"Wait for termination"* property along with the *"wait for output streams"* property.

Is my problem stems from that difference, and if so, is there any way configuring the new action as well?

Comment: How long does your main method take to return? Windows requires that it returns in less than 30 seconds by default

Comment: I guess this is the problem. if it does exceed 30 seconds - is there any way to config it to wait, like the "Wait for termination"  property?

Comment: No, that is a Windows configuration, see https://serverfault.com/questions/622432/how-do-i-increase-windows-service-startup-timeout